# monochromatic cycle-free colouring of the complete graph on R?

Tags: ramsey-theory, co.combinatorics, set-theory

Hi

So there is an edge-colouring of a complete graph on R (the reals), with countably many colours that as no monochromatic triangle. To find it map R to (0,1) write the numbers in binary and if 2 numbers differ 1st in the kth digit use colour k.

Now this colouring has cycles of length 4. (1/4, 3/4, 1/3, 2/3 for example). You can get rid of cycles of length 4 by considering the 1st 2  binarary digits in which 2 numbers differ (and of course seperate colours if they only differ in 1 digit). Anyway my question is can we avoid cycles completely? i.e. does there exist a colouring of the complete graph on R such that there is no monochromatic cycle.

Comment: You should precise from the beginning that you are considering *edge* coloring.

Comment: (@Benoît Kloeckner: Il y a un défaut tragique de traduction précise pour "préciser"; ici on dirait "specify" ou "clarify".)

Comment: If the color of an edge comes from the pair of first binary differences, wouldn't (1/5, 4/5, 1/6, 5/6) give a monochromatic 4-cycle?  Or did I misunderstand your construction?

Comment: @Tracy: The 1st construction I gave has no 3 cycles but as you say does have 4-cycles. The question was weather there is a "better" colouring which does not have any cycles.

Comment: @Jonathan: I was talking about the second, supposedly 4-cycle-free construction.  The 4-cycle (1/5, 4/5, 1/6, 5/6) alternates between binary expansions starting .00 and .11, and so as I understood your edge-coloring each step would be colored {1,2}: a monochromatic 4-cycle.  This seems to be a fundamental problem with the approach: if there is some pair of numbers $p$ and $q$ such that the rule coloring the edge from $p$ to $q$ depends on only the first digits (or neglects any digit at all), then changing a neglected digit of $p$ and a neglected digit of $q$ yields a monochromatic 4-cycle.  

Comment: @Tracy: Now I see what you mean. Yes you're completely right my construction doesn't work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that the existence of such a coloring is equivalent to the continuum hypothesis. This was proved by Erdos and Kakutani in 1943 in the paper "On non-denumerable graphs". They prove:

> A complete graph of cardinal number $m$ (that is, the cardinal number of the vertices is $m$) can be split up into a countable number of trees if and only if $m\le \aleph_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference ! I am trying to read the beginning of this paper [1], and I am stuck somewhere though. They are splitting all the intervals according to some notion of "length" (the $G_n$), then taking the union of all of them. Well, I do not get why there are not as many $G_n$ as $\omega_1$ :-/

Or does it mean that an initial section of a well ordered set of power $\omega_1$ is of cardinal at most $\omega_0 ?

If you think some reading may be fitting in this case.. Thanks ! :-)

[1] http://www.ams.org/bull/1943-49-06/S0002-9904-1943-07954-2/S0002-9904-1943-07954-2.pdf

Comment: Nathann, every initial segment of the ordinal $\omega_1$ is countable, if this is what you are asking. This is because $\omega_1$ is the smallest uncountable ordinal, by definition.

Answer (score 4):

Let me add to the above answer by noting that a stronger result holds and that, in the absence of the Continuum Hypothesis, the problems with the attempted construction of a 4-cycle-free coloring are unavoidable.

To fix notation, if $X$ is a set, $[X]^2$ is the set of 2-element subsets of $X$. We show that any coloring $c:[\omega_2]^2 \rightarrow \omega$ has a monochromatic 4-cycle. This will also give a shorter proof of the negative direction of the Erdos-Kakutani result mentioned above.

Fix $c:[\omega_2]^2 \rightarrow \omega$. For each $\omega_1 \leq \gamma < \omega_2$, find $n_\gamma < \omega$ such that $A^\gamma_{n_\gamma} := \{\alpha < \gamma \mid c(\{\alpha, \gamma\}) = n_\gamma\}$ is uncountable. Find a stationary $S \subseteq \omega_2$ and an $n^* < \omega$ such that, for all $\gamma \in S$, $n_\gamma = n^*$. For each $\gamma \in S$, let $\alpha_\gamma = \min(A^\gamma_{n^*})$, and let $\beta_\gamma = \min(A^\gamma_{n^*} \setminus (\alpha_\gamma + 1))$. By Fodor's Lemma, we can find $\alpha^* < \beta^* < \omega_2$ and a stationary $T \subseteq S$ such that, for all $\gamma \in T$, $(\alpha_\gamma, \beta_\gamma) = (\alpha^*, \beta^*)$. Fix $\gamma < \delta$, both in $T$. Then $c(\{\alpha^*, \gamma\}) = c(\{\gamma, \beta^*\}) = c(\{\beta^*, \delta\}) = c(\{\delta, \alpha^*\}) = n^*$, giving us a monochromatic 4-cycle.

Comment: Erdos and Kakutani ask at the end of that beautiful 1943 paper whether if CH fails, and the sets $M_n$ consist of rationally independent numbers, then $\bigcup M_n$ has inner measure 0. Was this ever answered?

Comment: @Avshalom This looks true to me. If you ask this as a separate question I will try to check the details and write an answer.

Comment: @Ashutosh Question posted; looking forward to your answer!