# Translates of measure zero set

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has measure zero. Can we find an uncountable $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $X + A = \bigcup \{a + x: a \in A, x \in X\}$ has measure zero?

Clearly, the answer is yes under Martin's axiom and $\mathfrak{c} > \aleph_1$. But can we do this without additional assumptions.

Comment: You'll be able to make comments and edits if you register your account.

Answer (score 10):

Claim: For every null G-delta set $X$, there exists a perfect set $P$ such that $X + P$ is null.

Proof sketch: First assume MA plus $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_2$. Choose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of size $\aleph_2$ and a null G-delta set $G$ such that $X + A \subseteq G$. It follows that $\{y: X + y \subseteq G\}$ is a coanalytic set of size $> \aleph_1$ and hence contains a perfect set $P$. The statement "there exist a perfect set P and a null G-delta set G such that $X + P \subseteq G$" is $\Sigma^1_2(X)$. Apply Shoenfield's absoluteness.

Note that the proof is identical to Martin's proof of Claim 1 [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206282/under-neg-ch-have-countable-unions-of-rationally-independent-numbers-inner-m).

Comment: The assumption that $X$ is $G_\delta$ is not needed: an arbitrary null $X$ is included in a null $G_\delta$ set anyway.